# Swap Animation Showing when going to different layout/activity. Button Bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, buttonbar

I got the button bar to work throughout the layouts and activities. I am getting a "swap" animation when I press a different button and pressing "back" on my phone sends me back to all the previous activities/layouts.. The buttons works fine and I think it has something to do with the intent in my java. Would ViewFlipper be a better alternative in this situation? Or is it possible to remove this using Intent. Thanks

buttonbar.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:shrinkColumns="*"  
android:stretchColumns="*" 
android:background="#6B1414">
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="@string/Str"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="18dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="#424242"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:text="@string/Agl"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="18dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="#424242"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:text="@string/Int"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="18dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="#424242"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:text="@string/Misc"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="#424242"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="18dip"/>
</TableRow> 
</TableLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn4 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainAgil.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.agil_main);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });


    btn3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainInt.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.int_main);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });


    btn4.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMisc.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.misc_main);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting new activities, and each new activity, something like a stack is being pushed. Back button just do its actual job, getting back for last activity. If you're really trying to maintain a button bar, try fragments

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks, I read over the guide, but I'm confused how this would be implemented with a button bar. Any examples? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a layout with yout button bar and above, or any place you want, put a framelayout or fragment itself. Is that link there is a good example. Be patient and read it. :) Don't forget to mark this answer as accept and right. Good to me.